# When was the first sauna on a ship?

Tags: naval, architecture, age-of-sail, tradition, ceremony

Heat baths or sweat lodges such as the Russian [*banya*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banya_%28sauna%29) and the [*temescal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temazcal) of the Mesoamericans are common around the world, especially where it gets cold. These insulated, purpose-built structures are built around a specific heat source to reach a high interior temperature. Some have water features and others are dry. [Plenty](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifestyle/8-unexpected-benefits-sauna-that-will-impress-you.html) of [reasons](https://www.drwhitaker.com/health-benefits-of-a-sauna) explain [why](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-24328773) people like to use heat baths. The necessary technology is ancient.

While space and fuel are at a premium on almost any boat, a cold ocean voyage seems to call for trips to the sauna. They are now easy to find on large yachts and cruise ships. What was the first heat bath on a seagoing vessel?

Comment: There could well be a sizable time difference between the very first example (which could be on a vanity project for a rich (royal?) owner) and the point when they first became commonplace. For the latter, I'd guess after the age of sail, when vessels became larger and required comparatively smaller crews. Heat from the steam engines could also have been diverted to provide heat for the sauna.

Comment: Wouldn't the amount of fuel necessary to produce enough heat generally be more of an issue than the space needed for the sauna itself or any safety issue regarding fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technologically it became not only possible, but easy in the time of cannon ships - when they started to heat the cannon balls to lit the enemy ships. If they could keep hot cannon balls, they could keep the hot stones without litting up the own ship. or to use these balls. Relatively closed space and pouring the water on these stones make no problem by itself. In travels by foot a tent was used, on the ship a sail could be used. Not a problem.

So, Russian, Norwegian and Swedish (Danish?) war ships could make a sauna, they loved it, it was a natural part of life for them, and every time when they had enough wood, surely, they did it.

About when that possibility was realized. When I have read the description of the travel of Bellisgauzen and Lazarev in which they open Antarctida, *banya* ( = sauna with a bit vapour) was mentioned as a weekly (on Saturdays) washing for the command. And it was something absolutely natural, not special for that expedition. It was not thorougly described there, only something as "After banya, when the free shift was resting on the deck, checking and repairing their uniforms, ropes and spare sails...".  It is 1819-1821 years. I don't have earlier references.

As for former times, when ships used cabotage courses, the sauna on board was simply useless and dangerous. Games with fire are dangerous on a wooden ship. Any ship owner could have such caprice, but if somebody had registered that?

As for Vikings, they could be the first in on board sauna use. Their travels in the open sea lasted for several days. They needed it and they could do it. But now mentions known to me.

Japanese and Chinese term in light variant was simply a large barrel of hot water.  Absolutely no problems to use that on big enough boat, you should only have enough wood and an oven.

Comment: Technologically having fire / heated stones on a ship was *possible* a lot earlier. Incendiary weapons were believed to be used as early as Rhoses, 300 BC (Casson, Lionel, The Ancient Mariners: Seafarers and Sea Fighters of the Mediterranean in Ancient Times Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ. 1991. ISBN 0-691-06836-4, p. 139), and I don't see how any culture that had invented [braziers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazier) couldn't use them on a ship. The question is, why should they...

Comment: The expedition happened in 1819-1821.

Comment: I can't find their book online, but the text suggests that the Vostok and/or the Mirny had a purpose-built banya on board?

Comment: @AaronBrick A metal sheet for hot cannon balls or stones, and a tent of a sail over it. That is enough. You don't need to *build* it.

Comment: But you do need to allocate space for it, have a container for the heat source, and seal or insulate to some degree, at least on an Antarctic voyage. Hard to believe the banya could be a jury-rigged afterthought on a voyage like that.

Comment: Wouldn't the amount of fuel necessary to produce enough heat generally be more of an issue than the space or technology needed for the banya/sauna itself or any safety issue regarding fire?

Comment: @Relaxed In warm waters they put a sail into the sea and bathed there. But it was impossible in the cold waters. And Russian culture demanded every week washing - a person had to go to the Sunday sermon clean. And they had to warm their premises anyway. Don't you think they were in Antarctica waters without that? So, they had fuel for warmth anyway.

Comment: @AaronBrick I can't be sure, what they used for sauna - tent or that small cabin in which normally ropes and sails lie.  But I do remember, that the rest after sauna included ropes and spare sails check and repair. It is very possible. Sorry, there was no description of the sauna in the book, only the fact that on the open sea they were in state after sauna.

Comment: @Gangnus Obviously, they had fuel, it seems you misunderstood my point and have never considered seriously the constraints of such expeditions. The real question is how much fuel for what purpose. It's precisely because you need it so sorely and can find locally that you need to budget its use carefully. How much fuel do you need to warm a few litres of snow to 30-40ºC and wash with it? How much to keep living quarters at a liveable 10ºC? How much to heat a room full of air to 90ºC?

Comment: @Relaxed Don't forget, Russian sauna has not 90 C, but about 60 C degrees. Softly moist 60C is enough. And you don't really need warm water for washing. The outdoor Russian sauna is very economical. Every 15 min next 5 men come in with a fresh red-hot cannonball. 15 min of sweating, scrubbing and washing. After getting out each gets a pail of cold water over the head. Or several. Really cheap.

Comment: @Gangnus I have never done it in Russia itself but that's not what I am reading or recall from the times I have been to something called “banya”. In any case, heating a room costs more energy than heating a limited quantity of water and 60º is hotter than 30ºC, it definitely does not sound economical to me. The fact that your only source is not before the 19th century and only for the officers confirms that it wasn't so easy.

Comment: Thank you for the Bellinghausen and Lazarev reference. It's very plausible that their expedition was the first to do so, and it sounds just as likely to have first happened centuries earlier.

Comment: By the way, I see no reason that rocks could not have been used instead of cannonballs.

Comment: @AaronBrick A ship of 1820 already had cannonballs. And had a special oven for heating them. Of course, stones are better for sauna, but you need to get them - big enough, round, solid - that means the additional work or money.

Comment: @AaronBrick And don't forget, that Western Europe started to wash weekly only after WWII. So, do not seek for sauna on English/French/German ships of XIX cent, let alone XVIII - then they had not even toilets yet. In Versailles toilets were built in the second half of XVIII cent.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because Chamisso described the crew of the _Rurik_ (1815-1818) being able to enjoy Russian baths on land in Kamchatka.